# Accessing uninitialized memory in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management, double-pointer

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i = 3;
    int *k;
    k = &i;
    k++;
    printf("%d ",*k);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output : Garbage value**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   int i = 3;
   int *j;
   int **k;
   j = &i;
   k = &j;
   k++;
   printf("%d ",**k);
   return 0;
}
```

**Output:Runtime error**

In both the programs k is a pointer variable and  it access the uninitailzed memory.
My Question is why it returns as runtime error in the second program

Comment: It's undefined behavior. You get what you get.

Comment: While it's all undefined behavior, dereferencing a garbage pointer is more likely to cause some sort of runtime error than deferencing an off-by-one pointer. In the second one `*k` is a garbage pointer value, so `**k` dereferences a garbage pointer.

Comment: [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, `k++` increments `k` to point to the memory after `i`. While accessing this memory is not defined by C, in common implementations (and particularly where optimization by the compiler has not significantly changed the code), `i` is stored on the stack. The stack is used for other things as well, so there is other accessible memory before and after `i`, and using `*k` may fetch data from this memory.

In the second example, `k++` increments `k` to point to the memory after `j`. Then `*j` may fetch data from this memory, as with the first example. Then `**j` may use that data as a pointer to access other memory. But the contents of `*j` are not generally a meaningful address. Quite likely, they form an address that is not mapped in the virtual memory space of your process. Attempting to access that address results in the hardware generating a fault.